# What are the cases where NLTK's word_tokenize differs from str.split()?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

Is there documentation where I can find all the possible cases where `word_tokenize` is different/better than simply splitting by whitespace? If not, could a semi-thorough list be given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word_tokenize documentation: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/nltk.word_tokenize

The NLTK tokenize package documentation: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html